# How to extracr name of dataframe form the of datafrrames in R?

Tags: r

I faced a small problem of exctracting names of dataframes from list of dataframes. Let me provide you with small example.

Assume I have three dataframes (`data1`, `data2`, `data3` and it doesn't matter the content of dataframes) and I put them into list like shown below.

```
my_list <- list(data1, data2, data3)
```

And I'd like to print their names in loop like this:

```
for (d in my_list){
  cat(deparse(substitute(d)))}
```

As a result I've got `ddd` but I want `data1`, `data2`, `data3` as a character.

How coul I resolve this kind of problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is the list `my_list` that you are creating doesn't have any names assigned to its elements. To solve this you can use `lst` function from `dplyr`.

```
my_list <- dplyr::lst(data1, data2, data3)
```

And then to get the names as a single comma-separated string you can do:

```
cat(names(my_list), sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dplyr::lst` which will assign the names to the list as per the dataframe name.

```
my_list <- dplyr::lst(data1, data2, data3)
```

To get names you can do `names(my_list)`.

and in loop :

```
for (d in names(my_list)) {
  name <- d
  data <- my_list[[d]]
}
```